# TagLib - Teste de condição entre JSP e MODEL

Tags: java, validação, if

Estou tentando fazer minha JSP (index.jsp) executar uma condição (if) com taglib, para decidir qual menu ela vai importar, dependendo de um atributo (permissao(boolean)) que esta na model (usuario.java).

Já realizei o debug para verificar se o método +validar esta puxando as informações correta do banco. Esta funcionando normal.

Mas o problema esta em passar isso para a JSP, para ela conseguir fazer o teste.

O teste que estou tentando fazer é simples:

```
<c:if test ="${usuario.permissao == true}">
    <c:import url="MenuAdmin.jsp"/>
</c:if>
```

Esse é meu código do command, onde realizo a validação de login. (Não sei se estou passando de forma correta para a JSP.)

```
public class FazerLogin implements Command {
    @Override
    public void executar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    String login = request.getParameter("username");
    String senha = request.getParameter("password");

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.setUsuario(login);
    usuario.setSenha(senha);
    UsuarioService service = new UsuarioService();

    if(service.validar(usuario)){
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario.getUsuario());
        System.out.println("Logou "+ usuario.getUsuario());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não logou "+ usuario.getUsuario());
        throw new ServletException("Usuario/Senha inválidos");
    }
    request.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);
    response.sendRedirect("Index.jsp");
}}
```

Quando eu faço o teste para verificar se a {usuario.permissao == false}, ele retorna true. Mas o estranho que o método no debug, mostra que a permissao esta true.

Comment: quando você faz `request.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);` você não queria fazer `request.setAttribute("usuario", usuario.getUsuario());` ?

Comment: Mas o usuario  já esta estanciado

Comment: Então, este usuario novo só tem login e senha (pelo menos é o que dava pra ver neste codigo) onde você esta colocando a permissao ?

Comment: Dentro do metodo validar

Comment: try {
   Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.obtemConexao();
   try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(sqlSelect);) {
    stm.setString(1, usuario.getUsuario());
    stm.setString(2, usuario.getSenha());
    stm.execute();
    try (ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();) {
     if (rs.next()) {
      usuario.setPermissao(rs.getBoolean("permissao"));
      return true;
     } else {
      return false;
     }

É só uma parte do metodo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver a questão da JSP entender o parametro.

Alterei na validação de:

```
request.setAttribute para session.setAttribute
```

Agora o problema esta em trocar de menu. Pois quando o usuario loga, a "index.html" ela importa o "menu.jsp". Dentro do "menu.jsp" tem um if.

```
<c:if test="${usuario.permissao == true}">
reponse.sendRedirect("MenuAdmin.jsp");
</c:if>
```

Mas não esta funcionado esse redirect. Seria esse código mesmo ?
Pois não encontrei nenhum outro redirect.